# PHP trim and keep only first and last part

Tags: php

I have variables as follow in PHP

```
steve_s_baue
marine_camp_se_bell
mike_wane
```

I want to only keep the first and last part:

```
steve_baue
marine_bell
mike_wane
```

I tried to use `trim` but got stuck.

**EDIT: Here is what I tried to far**

```
$row = $pre_results[$i];    
$name = $row -> name;
$text = preg_replace('~[^\pL\d]+~u', '_', $name);
$text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
$text = preg_replace('~[^-\w]+~', '', $text);
$text = trim($text, '_');
$text = preg_replace('~-+~', '_', $text);
$text = strtolower($text);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Use a regex and preserve the first and last word? Or explode on the underscore and implode the first and last element with an underscore

Comment: Didn't you just ask this half an hour ago?

Comment: Who upvoted this? They didn't show *any* effort to write this themselves.

Comment: @JohnConde I got to replacing non-letter, transliterate, removing unwanted characters, trimming and removing duplicates and lowercaseing. But having a bit difficult time with removing anything in between between first and last.

Comment: @JohnConde Just because I decided to keep things simple in the question, doesn't mean I didn't put any effort. Stop down voting it. It's not my first time asking questions here. I know the rule.

Comment: @steveKim Be fair to them; they could not tell that from your question and I arrived right as you were editing it. They did the right thing given what they had at the moment. They are trying to keep the site clean and within context...:-)

Comment: try reading until the first underscore and then find the last underscore and read till the end, concatenate string and output, using regex will be difficult, also if these are first name, last name you are storing them in a wrong way.

Comment: @Shawn I know what you mean. I used to be able to edit things before I got any comments (After reading my own question once it was submitted). But now, I get instant downvote from JohnConde even before I get a chance to go over them and see what is needed. I am sure he is just doing his job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function firstlast($var,$seperator) {
     $varr = explode($seperator, $var);
     $first = current($varr);
     $last = end($varr);
     return $first.'_'.$last;
}
$seperator='_';
$old = 'marine_camp_se_bell';
$new = firstlast($old, $seperator);
echo $new;
```

If you put original strings in an array, you can run array_walk(); with this function

Comment: I see. It seems like that's the only viable way doing it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this: 
http://nimb.ws/dVHzZJ and 
http://nimb.ws/ENgTCm

```
<?php
$a = "steve_s_baue";
$temp=explode("_",$a);
$arr=array($temp[0],$temp[2]);
print_r(implode("_",$arr));
?>
```

Comment: It's not always, 3rd key of array

Comment: I have just given example and not a perfect code to copy and paste in his project.

Answer (score 1):

Do it with explode function, I made a basic example working

```
 <?php 

$name = "marine_camp_se_bell";
$var = explode("_",$name);
print_r (explode("_",$name));
//than print as array
echo "</br>";
echo $var[0];
echo "</br>";
echo $var[3];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = "john_dont_do_some_doe";
$array = explode("_", $name);
$last = count($array) - 1;
echo $array[0]."_". $array[$last];  //shows: john_doe
```

*not tested, but should do the job